# "Is the situation at company X that bad?"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, prepositions

I heard company X was going through a hiring freeze and asked a friend working for that company about it. He told me that it was indeed on a hiring freeze and it affected candidates of all seniorities/levels. Then I asked:

> Is the situation at company X that bad?

I meant to ask how company X was doing generally.

I wonder if the proposition should be 'for'  or 'of' as in

> Is the situation for/of company X that bad?

What are some other ways of expressing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original sentence (with "at") is perfectly fine and common.

The prepositions "of" and "for" also make sense, although the meanings are a bit different. For example, if Company Y was planning a new strategy that would force Company X into bankruptcy, then "of" or "for" might work better than "at", because although the development certainly affects Company X, it is occurring elsewhere. I don't consider this to be a major issue, though.

Some writers might also use "with", "regarding", "concerning", etc. In the situation that you describe, I think that "at" works best.